# Magento 1 : Incorrect Search Title Showing

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, seo

Making a website on Magento 1.9, I have created a title for the website to show on search engines. But on all ones am getting wrong title name. can anyone guide how to make correct the same?

as my title for the website is: Online Shopping Site in India for Women's Clothing, Cosmetics& More With Free Shipping

But on search engines, this is what shows
[image]

I doubt if I made a mistake. can anyone please guide in this regards?

Comment: When did you updated the titles?

Comment: Around 15 days earlier.

Comment: Try to submit for crawling  to Google.

Comment: i already did it for around 2-3 times, still its not getting sorted. is it crawler issue or from my backend ?